# ora-00937 Not a single-group group function - issues with count

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select au_lname, au_fname, count(titles.title)
from titleauthor
join titles ON titles.title_id=titleauthor.title_id
join authors ON authors.au_id=titleauthor.au_id
having COUNT(titles.title) > 2;
```

I keep receiving the ora-00937 error, but I'm not entirely clear why it's not a single-group group function. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: you have to include `group by au_lname, au_fname` before `having`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need a `group by`:

```
select a.au_lname, a.au_fname, count(*)
from titleauthor ta join
     authors a
     ON a.au_id = ta.au_id
having COUNT(*) > 2;
```

In addition, you don't need to join to `titles` -- unless some of the titles are actually `NULL` or duplicated (which seems unlikely).